# Black output with image manipulation in Tensorflow (using a jpeg decoder for Neural net training)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have access to a large amount of 2048x2048x3 jpeg pictures which I am storing in the TFRecords binary format. Later, I use the stored files to train a deep neural network. To store the pictures, I am currently using two different methods.

The first one uses tensorflow. I have defined a function that creates a Tensorflow graph. I keep reusing the same graph for all the pictures:

```
def picture_decoder(height, width):
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        picture_name_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        picture_contents = tf.read_file(picture_name_tensor)
        picture = tf.image.decode_jpeg(picture_contents)
        picture_as_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(picture, tf.float32)
        picture_4d = tf.expand_dims(picture_as_float, 0)
        resize_shape = tf.stack([height, width])
        resize_shape_as_int = tf.cast(resize_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
        final_tensor =  tf.image.resize_bilinear(picture_4d, resize_shape_as_int)
    return g, picture_name_tensor, final_tensor

Height, Width = 300, 300
graph, nameholder, image_tensor = picture_decoder(Height, Width)                                        
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    init = tf.group( tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer() )
    sess.run(init)

    #Loop through the  pictures
    for(...picture_name...):
        picture = sess.run(image_tensor, feed_dict={nameholder: picture_name} )
```

The second method uses numpy:

```
def picture_decoder_numpy(picture_name, height, width):
    image = Image.open(picture_name)
    image = image.resize((height,width), Image.LANCZOS)
    image = np.array(image, dtype=np.int32)                             
    return np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

Heigth, Width = 300, 300
for(...picture_name...):
    picture = picture_decoder_numpy(pict, Height, Width)
```

The first method appears to be approximately 6 times faster than the second one.

The issue I am facing is related with the training afterwards. For the first case, the deep neural net I have defined does not learn, i.e., its loss does not improve over many epochs and it is only slightly smaller than 1. Using the second method, *without changing any neural net parameter*, the loss achieves E-05 values. Am I missing some Tensorflow detail?

I can post the full code if necessary.

**Update:**

The method using Tensorflow outputs a black picture, while the method using numpy works as expected.

MVCE for decoding the pictures:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def picture_decoder(height, width):
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        picture_name_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        picture_contents = tf.read_file(picture_name_tensor)
        picture = tf.image.decode_jpeg(picture_contents, dct_method="INTEGER_ACCURATE")
        picture_as_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(picture, tf.float32)
        picture_4d = tf.expand_dims(picture_as_float, 0)
        resize_shape = tf.stack([height, width])
        resize_shape_as_int = tf.cast(resize_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
        final_tensor =  tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_bilinear(picture_4d, resize_shape_as_int))
    return g, picture_name_tensor, final_tensor

def picture_decoder_numpy(picture_name, height, width):
    image = Image.open(picture_name)
    image = image.resize((height,width), Image.LANCZOS)
    return np.array(image, dtype=np.int32)


pic_name = "picture.jpg"
#Numpy method                                                                                            
#picture = picture_decoder_numpy(pic_name, 300, 300)                                                     

#Tensorflow method                                                                                       
graph, nameholder, picture_tensor = picture_decoder(300, 300)
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    init = tf.group()
    sess.run(init)
    picture = sess.run(picture_tensor, feed_dict={nameholder: pic_name})

im = Image.fromarray(picture.astype('uint8'))
im.save("save.jpg")
```

Comment: How about a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, I believe at some point you expect some results to be the same. Have you checked that this is happening?

Comment: @norok2 I was precisely doing that check. I have updated the question and added a MCVE.

Comment: MVCE does not work in Py3 using Anaconda latest. Seems there is a problem with `resize_shape = tf.stack(height, width)` (which is different in the above code). Also, you probably want to include some code to check that the two methods give similar/identical results.

Comment: @norok2 The MVCE is now working. Sorry for the inconvenience. I can add the method you mentioned as soon as I understand why the tensorflow decoder function outputs everything in black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TF implementation does not do what you think it does. The problem is that the image value get converted to the `(1, 0)` range, while in the `numpy` way, values are in the `(255, 0)` range.

One way to solve it is to multiply your final result by `255`.

```
def picture_decoder(height, width):
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        picture_name_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        picture_contents = tf.read_file(picture_name_tensor)
        picture = tf.image.decode_jpeg(picture_contents, dct_method="INTEGER_ACCURATE")
        picture_as_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(picture, tf.float32)
        picture_4d = tf.expand_dims(picture_as_float, 0)
        resize_shape = tf.stack([height, width])
        resize_shape_as_int = tf.cast(resize_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
        final_tensor =  tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_bilinear(picture_4d, resize_shape_as_int)) * 255  # FIX: rescale to typical 8-bit range
    return g, picture_name_tensor, final_tensor
```

Of course, the two array should not match exactly as you use two different interpolation methods as well.

```
norm_dist = np.abs(np.sum(arr - arr2)) / (np.sum(arr) + np.sum(arr2)) / 2
np.isclose(norm_dist, 0, atol=1e-4)
True
```

(assuming `arr` contains the `numpy` implementation, and `arr2` the `tensorflow` one).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will train the neural net with this modification as see what happens. By the way, when I run the snippet you posted above, I get huge differences, much larger than the tolerance you specified. Did you really get `True`?

Comment: That number really depends on the input, perhaps bilinear filtering is really not appropriate for your inputs

Comment: Eventually, a perhaps more intuitive way of doing this is to compute the mean squared error `mse = np.mean(np.sqrt((arr - arr2) ** 2))`, which should be `mse < 1`.